# Generate exe from Xamarin.From - UWP project

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I have created a project with Xamarin.Forms - Android / iOS / UWP version for it.

Now if I want to generate an exe from that, which procedure I need to follow?

Comment: build your UWP project

Comment: But that exe I cannot run individually

Comment: Please check the below answer. And I have perfected it.

Answer (score 0):

> But that exe I cannot run individually.

After building your UWP project, you will find `ProjectName.exe` in debug folder. Actually the `ProjectName.exe` file is your current application's executable file. And you could verify this by checking `Package.appxmanifest` in  UWP project.

```
<Application Id="App"
  Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
  EntryPoint="MuiltSelectPicker.UWP.App">
```

However, it could not be executed directly. Because UWP apps run sandboxed. And it will depend on some dll file. If you want to execute the app, you could package your UWP app, and sideload the app package directly on a device. For more you could refer the following description.

> Now if I want to generate an exe from that, which procedure I need to follow?

It is similar to classical UWP. You could refer to the classical UWP packaging process.

[Package a UWP app with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps). It shows you how to package with Visual Studio.

And you could also create an app package with the [MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).